# How to write Multi Aggs in elastic search 8.9

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to do a terms aggregation on two fields. Is it possible to combine these two queries into one? I tried it with the below request is fetching a not properly filtered which is written in include "P_SAL". In the output source prod is displayed with other values also along with P_SAL. I do want to show only P_SAL.
Input:

```
{
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "c_no": {
                            "query": "3M"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "joh",
                        "operator": "and",
                        "type": "cross_fields",
                        "tie_breaker": "1.0",
                        "fields": [
                            "a_line1",
                            "a_line2",
                            "a_line3",
                            "a_line4",
                            "a_line5",
                            "a_line6",
                            "a_line7",
                            "i_name"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "prod": {
            "terms": {
                "fi": "prod",
                "include":[ 
                    "P_SAL"
                ]
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "e_date": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```